# Structure Data NoSQL

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm quite new to NoSQL, that's why I come here to get your opinions.

I'm trying to understand if it's better to use nested object or subcollections in a specific case. I will try to explain my case.

I have to store several shops in my Db. Each shop will have an address, a phone number etc... So I have a Collection "Shop" and inside several Documents representing the shops.
Now, my shops have some contacts (2,3 or 4 employees for example). My question is, what should I do :

- Store in my "shop" documents 2,3 or 4 objects like :

`objectContact: {
    name: "Georges",
    age: 20....
    }`

- Create a subcollections "Contact" inside my "shop" documents, and then insert 2,3 or 4 documents in this subcollections.

Which is the better ? Does one of this two solutions disable some tools/queries in NoSQL ? Does one of this two solutions is faster when it comes to write/read the data ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "nosql" is not a database. What are you actually using, mongodb?

Comment: Sorry, I misuse the word database. I'm using firebase/firestore

Comment: firebase database or firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, all the queries in the cloud firestore are shallow which means you can't get the subcollection with its collection.You have read it separately. So I would recommend you to store it in a nested document. But it has few limitations though.  [Check this link for detailed explanation of modelling data in cloud firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess that's what I'm going for.